# how to prevent popup window on right mouse click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup, right-click

I need to disable popup window on right mouse click using javascript. Because I want to open another popup window on right click.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Please try that:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Actually, it's annoying, when you can't use right mouse on a website.

You can disable it for any particular block in the same way:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $('#test').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    }); 
});​
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="test"> ​No right clicks allowed here! </div>​
```

And sample CSS:

```
#test { width: 200px; height: 200px; background: red; }
```

And, finally, an example

Answer (score -1):

Copy the JS file [here](http://demo.mistonline.in/menu/menu.js) as menu.js and include the same in your html file path.

menu.css file

```
ul.SimpleContextMenu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 12px;
list-style-type: none;
border-top: 1px solid #000000;
border-left: 1px solid #000000;
border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}ul.SimpleContextMenu li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
ul.SimpleContextMenu li a {
display: block;
//menu width
width: 200px;
padding: 2px 10px 3px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
//Menu font color
color: #ff0000;
//Menu background color
background: #eeeeee;
}
ul.SimpleContextMenu li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
background: #ff0000;
}
```

html file

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SimpleContextMenu.setup({'preventDefault':true}); //prevent default
SimpleContextMenu.attach('container1', 'CM1');
SimpleContextMenu.attach('container2', 'CM2');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"><ul id="CM1" class="SimpleContextMenu">
<li><a href="https://link_1_here">link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="https://link_2_here">link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="https://link_2_here">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="container1" style="border: 1px dashed red; margin-top: 30px; height: 50px; background: #f2f2f2;">Right Click Here To See The Menu</div>
</div>
</html>
```

This works fine in Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this code, but it preventing right click also. I need to open customized popup on right click

Comment: There is a tutorial out here, which has step by step intrucstions on how to build a custom JavaScript context menu. See if this helps https://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/

Comment: I have done using SWT. But i need to prevent the default popup window. Any idea??

Comment: I have modified my answer with an example code. See if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. its working fine in html page. But when i using javascript code in java class that time it will not work.